# regular expression is not producing the expected result in hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I want to replace non-ASCII characters with empty space in hive query. I tried below query. But it is not working..

```
select regexp_replace(col_name, '[^\u0000-\u007F]+', '')
```

What am I doing wrong here? any clues will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Joe, if possible, can you please give example of non-ASCII characters that you are trying to replace in your question, I am trying select regexp_replace("Big¿¿©Data", '[^\u0000-\u007F]+', ''); and its giving me output by replacing ¿¿© char with space.

Comment: @praxnet  When I execute the query select regexp_replace("Big¿¿©Data", '[^\u0000-\u007F]+', '')  in hive, I am getting  BD as result , everything else is replaced .. is that expected.

Comment: @praxnet ,, I am not able to paste the character in the comment box  that I am trying to replace.

Comment: What I meant was, select regexp_replace("Big¿¿©Data", '[^\u0000-\u007F]+', '')  -->  Output = BigData, non-ASCII characters replaced with space are  ¿¿©

Comment: Can you share a link of your non-ascii characters by putting it in some site like https://unicodelookup.com/#%C6%92/1

Answer (score 0):

remove the ^ as that is 'beginning of a string' marker